# How to query by date and time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have a table where my date/time is of form: 2020-03-10 22:54:08
This is a timestampped object.  I tried the following query but didn't return any rows:

```
select ts from table1 
where cast(ts as timestamp) = '2020-03-10 22:54:08'
```

returns nothing.

How do i query based on date and time in postgressql?

Comment: I know this sounds pedantic, but can you provide 1) table structure (`\d table1` -- what is the data type of `ts` column), 2) confirm that there actually exists a row where the timestamp is `2020-03-10 22:54:08`?

Comment: yea its a timestamp row.  I created it by using this: Create table my_table
        (
            portfolio_uuid text NULL,
            portfolio_family_id bigint NULL,
            ticker text NULL,
            size double precision NULL,
            secid bigint NULL,
            portfolio_name_id bigint NULL,
            ts timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
        );
    """

Answer (score 0):

Actually this worked.

```
select distinct(ts) from my_table where ts >= '2020-03-10 22:54:08' and ts <= '2020-03-10 22:54:09'
```

But this doesn't give me the whole rows

But then i tried this and this worked:

```
select ts from table1
where to_char(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = '2020-03-10 22:54:08'
```

Comment: The first one can use an index on `ts` (if there is any), the second cannot. So better go with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp has microsecond resolution, so you have to use same techiques as when testing floating point numbers: Round it or use only < and > for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data from a database, you need to refer to [SQL `SELECT` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-select.html).  In your situation, the `ts` column is already a timestamp, so there is no need to use `cast()`.  Bear in mind, however, that a `timestamp` type contains fractions of a second (i.e., `2020-03-10 22:54:03.xxx`), so you would be better off using a comparison operator (`>`,`<`,`>=`,or `<=`)

You can retrieve all columns by using the `*` syntax:

```
select *
from my_table
where ts >= '2020-03-10 22:54:08';
```

Answer (score 0):

`tymestamp` type by default contains also microseconds, so, `now()` which, for example, is `2020-03-11 01:56:27.593985` here obviously is not equal to `2020-03-11 01:56:27`. If you do not want to have microseconds precision in your data then declare your field like `ts timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT now()` which means "0 decimal digits for microseconds":

```
select
    current_timestamp::timestamp as ts,
    current_timestamp::timestamp(2) as ts2,
    current_timestamp::timestamp(0) as ts0;

            ts             |          ts2           |         ts0         
---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 2020-03-11 02:02:52.98298 | 2020-03-11 02:02:52.98 | 2020-03-11 02:02:53
```